# Can I use indexeddb across subdomains?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb, subdomain

I'm building a Chrome extension and using the db.js wrapper to utilize the indexeddb.  The problem is, I've got several subdomains and I'd like to be able to share the information across them.

When I use the Chrome Dev tools to view Resources, all of the individual subdomains have their own copy of the schema I'm creating, and each has it's own data.

The only thing I knew to try was to set the document.domain but that didn't help.  I wasn't surprised.

Documentation on indexeddb is very slim it seems.  I keep finding the same 2 or 3 blog posts copied word for word in several different blogs and nothing specifies that this is possible or impossible.

Answer (score 6):

You can't access the same database from multiple subdomains, the access scope is limited to [html origin](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/origin-0.html).

```
html_Origin = protocol + "://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/";
```

Comment: Also, it's a very minor nitpick, but you're using "url" as a variable name inappropriately - it doesn't contain the URL.  I think you might have meant to write "hostname" or "domain" instead?

Answer (score 4):

As @Xan mentioned, if you can use a common origin owned by the extension itself, rather than by the content pages, that sounds like it would be by far the easiest solution.  If for whatever reason you can't do that (or for readers who got here wanting to know about regular page javascript or Greasemonkey-style userscripts, rather than extensions), the answer is:

## Yes, though it's a slightly awkward and takes some work:

Since you're using a number of related subdomains, (rather than completely unrelated domains), there's a technique you can use in that situation.  It can be applied to `IndexedDB`, `localStorage`, `SharedWorker`, `BroadcastChannel`, etc, all of which offer shared functionality between same-origin pages, but for some reason don't respect modifications to `document.domain`.

(1) Pick one "main" subdomain to for the data to belong to. i.e. if your subdomains are *https://a.example.com*, *https://b.example.com*, and *https://c.example.com*, you might choose to have your IndexedDB database stored under the *https://a.example.com* subdomain.

(2) Use it normally from all the the *https://a.example.com* pages.

(3) On *https://b.example.com* and *https://c.example.com*, use javascript to set `document.domain = "example.com";`.  Then also create a hidden `<iframe>`, and navigate it to *some* page on the *https://a.example.com* domain (**It doesn't matter *what* page**, as long as you can insert a very little snippet of javascript on there.  If you're creating the site, just make an empty page specifically for this purpose.  If you're writing an extension or a userscript and so don't have any control over pages on the *example.com* server, just pick the most lightweight page you can find and insert your script into it.  Some kind of "not found" page would probably be fine).

(4) The script on the hidden iframe page need only (a) set `document.domain = "example.com";`, and (b) notify the parent window when this is done.  After that, the parent window can access the iframe window and all its objects without restriction!  So the minimal iframe page is something like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    document.domain = "example.com";
    window.parent.iframeReady();  // function defined & called on parent window
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

If writing a userscript, you might not want to add externally-accessible functions such as `iframeReady()` to your `unsafeWindow`, so instead a better way to notify the main window userscript might be to use a custom event:

```
    window.parent.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("iframeReady"));
```

Which you'd detect by adding a listener for the custom "iframeReady" event to your main page's window.

(5)  Once the hidden iframe has informed its parent window that it's ready, script in the parent window can just use `iframe.contentWindow.indexedDB`, `iframe.contentWindow.localStorage`, `iframe.contentWindow.BroadcastChannel`, `iframe.contentWindow.SharedWorker` instead of `window.indexedDB`, `window.localStorage` etc. ...and all these objects will be scoped to the *https://a.example.com* origin - so they'll have the this same shared origin for all of your pages!

The "awkward" part of this technique is mostly that you have to wait for the iframe to load before proceeding.  So you can't just blithely initialize IndexedDB in your DOMContentLoaded handler, for example.  Also you might want to add some error handling to detect if the hidden iframe fails to load correctly.

Obviously, you should also make sure the hidden iframe is not removed or navigated during the lifetime of your page... OTOH I don't know what the result of that would be, but very likely bad things would happen.

And, a caveat:  setting/changing `document.domain` can be **blocked** using the `Feature-Policy` header, in which case this technique will not be usable as described.

---

However, there is a significantly more-complicated generalization of this technique, that can't be blocked by `Feature-Policy`, and that also **allows entirely unrelated domains to share data, communications, and shared workers** (i.e. not just subdomains off a common superdomain).  @Xan alludes to it in point (2) of his answer:

The general idea is that, just as above, you create a hidden iframe to provide the correct origin for access; but instead of then just grabbing the iframe window's properties directly, you use script inside the iframe to do all of the work, and you communicate between the iframe and your main window only using `postMessage()` and `addEventListener("message",...)`.

This works because `postMessage()` can be used even between different-origin windows.  But it's also significantly more complicated because you have to pass everything through some kind of messaging infrastructure that you create between the iframe and the main window, rather than (for example) just using the IndexedDB API directly in your main window's code.

Comment: document.domain = "example.com";  was deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain#deprecation

Comment: @JuanmaMenendez deprecated, ya, means no way to access iframe indexeddb any more?

Comment: @Dee, deprecated doesn't necessarily mean you can't use it, only that it's not guaranteed to work in the future.  See also the effect of sending an `Origin-Agent-Cluster: ?0` header (if it's your own website), which may (apparently) re-enable the ability to set `document.domain` in supported browsers.

Answer (score 1):

HTML-based storage (indexedDB, localStorage) in Chrome extensions behaves in a way that might not be expected, but it's perfectly natural.

1. In the background page, the domain is `chrome-extension://yourextensionid/`, and this is shared by all extension pages and is persistent.
2. In the content scripts though, you're sharing the HTML storage with the domain you're operating on. This makes life difficult if you want it to share/persist things. Note that sometimes this behavior is actually helpful.

The universal solution is to keep the DB in a background script, and communicate data/requests by means of [Messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

This was the usual solution for `localStorage` use until `chrome.storage` came along. But since you're using a database, you don't have a ready extension-friendly replacement.